# Azure AD oauth springboot + vuejs

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, vue.js, azure-active-directory

I've got a VueJs app for the front and a springboot application for the backend.
I use msal browser to authenticate my user in my app from Azure and i've got my access_token
But now i'm stuck to introspect my access_token from my springboot application.
I've seen the flow from Azure but can't find this precise scenario where i've already authenticated my user.
Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Please rephrase. Do you need to achieve only a SSO login or you need to query Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you wanna you springboot application to authenticate the access token, if so, here's my idea.

First, I used msal in front end application to generate access token for calling api, then when I send ajax request, I added access token in request header. By the way, because of the front and back-end separation architecture, I need to add filter to avoid CORS. Then I need to create another filter to make sure the coming in request has unexpired token or has specific claim. Here's my code, and I just confirm the token is in the validity period. This is the [sdk doc](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) for decoding jwt token.

Front end:

```
function initPage2(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/hello2",
        type:'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        },
        data:{
            userId:"tiny"
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Backend code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTDecodeException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(jwtToken);
                Date expiresAt = jwt.getExpiresAt();
                if(expiresAt.before(new Date())) {
                    Map<String, Object> errRes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    Map<String, Object> errMesg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    errMesg.put("code", "InvalidAuthenticationToken");
                    errMesg.put("message", "Access token has expired.");
                    errRes.put("error", errMesg);
                    String json = JSONObject.toJSONString(errRes);   
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, json);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (JWTDecodeException exception){
                System.out.println("Unable to Decode the JWT Token");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acutally there is simpler way than the one provided by @tiny-wa.

Update:
I just found a even better example as the one I describe below.
Microsoft has a demo project using spring + vue: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory/aad-resource-server-by-filter-stateless

Old answer:
Since you already got your access token in the VueJS App. All you need is to do is look at this sample of an AAD resource server:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory/aad-resource-server

It automatically filters the "Bearer" token and validates it with AAD.

I suggest you to remove all the `@PreAuthorize` annotations form the `HomeController` class:

```
    @GetMapping("/user")
    @ResponseBody
//    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_User.Read')")
    public String user() {
        return "User read success.";
    }
```

And then add the following new class to the sample App:

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
package com.azure.spring.sample.aad;

import com.azure.spring.aad.webapi.AADResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends AADResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
    }
}
```

Doing this, you do not need to take care of custom `SCOPES` and just allow every authenticated user for testing purpose.

In your frontend you need to send the obtained token in the Authorization header of your request to the resource server.

Example:

```
axios
   .request({
      url: '/user',
      method: 'get',
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8082',
      headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>'
      }
   })
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
   })
```