# How to acquire an access token to a custom API using MSAL acquireTokenSilent?

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, acquiretokensilent

I am able to obtain a valid access token for the Graph API, as there is an abundant examples/docs/tutorials for this.

However, I am unable to obtain a valid access token for my custom API.
The scope I'm using looks something like this:

```
"api://<GUID VALUE>/user_impersonation"
```

Using this scope, I can obtain an access token. Unfortunately it is not valid. Subsequently I get a unauthorized 401 error when I try to invoke something on the custom API.

Is it even possible to request an access token on a custom API using MSAL **acquireTokenSilent**?

Comment: If you've got the access token which can be decoded to see the right scope, that means the token is all right, what you need to check is your api project, to check if the authentication is correctly set.

Comment: How on earth can I decode an access token???

Comment: Also, i am ale to verify the custom API is working via external tools, like Postman, and the like.

Comment: decode online: https://jwt.io/

Comment: What's your backend api language? is asp.net core you may refer to my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799358/15581227)

Comment: The JWT decoder is a tremendous tool! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, if you have further issue pls kindly share it, and if you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if the access token has been generated successfully, we can [decode it online](https://jwt.io/) and if the `scp` claim really contains the specific api permission (`scp` is for delegate api permission while `roles` for application permission), that always the backend api has issue to authentication but not the token is wrong.

And if your backend is written in asp.net core, you may refer to my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763252/azure-authentication-audience-validation-failed/68799358#68799358), for java or springboot backend, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65881687/14574199) may help.